# Pandas.rolling_correlation, threshold?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas.rolling_corr to calculate correlation of two Pandas series.

```
pd.rolling_corr(x, y, 10)
```

x and y have very little variation. For instance

```
x[0] = 1.3342323
x[1] = 1.3342317
```

Since correlation is covariance divided by standard deviation, the correlation should only be inf or -inf if the standard deviation is 0. However, in the data set that I have, values are very close but no values are exactly same as another. But for some reason, I'm getting inf or -inf values in the correlation.

Here is my question: Is there a limit in pandas.rolling_corr, in which the number is just automatically rounded in calculation if the number if too small? (x<1e-7)

the dataset that I'm working with (x and y) are in 'float64' and I have set the chop_threshold to 0.

EDITED*
Here's is a sample of data that I'm working with. I'm trying to compute the correlation between the two columns, but the result is inf.

```
1144    679.5999998
1144    679.600001
1143.75 679.6000003
1143.75 679.5999993
1143    679.6000009
```

Comment: Could you please upload a sample of your raw data? (for example, via a dropbox share link). Correlation is always between -1 and 1, and it is a meaningful concept only if your data is stationary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can more generally be considered as a question about precision rather than correlation.  And generally, you can expect things behind the scenes to be done at double precision which means that it's around 13 or 14 decimal places that things can get wonky (though certainly at 11 or 12 decimal places (or less) in many cases).

So here's a little example program that starts with differences of 1 in the 'x' column (1e0) and then drops it in steps all the way down to 1e-20.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:12,.9f}'.format
df_corr = pd.DataFrame()
diffs = np.arange(4)
for i in range(20):
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x': [1,1,1,1], 'y':[5,7,8,6] })
    df['x'] = df['x'] + diffs*.1**i
    df_corr = df_corr.append( pd.rolling_corr(df.x,df.y,3)[2:4], ignore_index=True )
```

A couple of comments before looking at results.  First, pandas default display will sometimes hide very small differences in numbers so you need to force more precise formatting in some way.  Here I used `pd.options`.

Second, I won't put a ton of comments in here, but the main thing you need to know is that the 'x' columns varies in each loop.  You can add a print statement if you like, but the first 4 iterations look like this:

```
iteration     values of column 'x'
0             [ 1.   2.     3.     4.    ]
1             [ 1.   1.1    1.2    1.3   ]
2             [ 1.   1.01   1.02   1.03  ]
3             [ 1.   1.001  1.002  1.003 ]
```

So by the time we get to later iterations, the differences will be so small that pandas just sees it as `[1,1,1,1]`.  The practical question then is at what point the differences are so small as to be indistinguishable to pandas.

To make this a little more concrete, this is what it looks like for the 8th iteration (and the `rolling_corr` uses a window of 3 since this dataset has only 4 rows):

```
             x  y
0  1.000000000  5
1  1.000000100  7
2  1.000000200  8
3  1.000000300  6
```

So here are the results, where the index value also gives the iteration number (and hence the precision of the differences in column 'x')

```
df_corr

              2            3
0   0.981980506 -0.500000000
1   0.981980506 -0.500000000
2   0.981980506 -0.500000000
3   0.981980506 -0.500000000
4   0.981980506 -0.500000000
5   0.981980506 -0.500000000
6   0.981980505 -0.500000003
7   0.981980501 -0.500000003
8   0.981980492 -0.499999896
9   0.981978898 -0.500001485
10  0.981971784 -0.500013323
11  0.981893289 -0.500133227
12  0.981244570 -0.502373626
13  0.976259968 -0.505124339
14  0.954868546 -0.132598709
15  0.785584405  1.060660172
16  0.000000000  0.000000000
17          nan          nan
18          nan          nan
19          nan          nan
```

So you can see there that you are getting reasonable results down to about the 13th decimal place (although accuracy is declining prior to that), and then they fall apart although you don't actually get NaNs until the 17th.

I'm not sure how to directly answer your question but hopefully that sheds some light.  I would say that there is really no such thing as automatic rounding that occurs in these calculations but it's hard to generalize.  It's certainly the case that some algorithms deal better than others with precision-type issues like this, but it's not possible to make any broad generalizations there, even amongst different functions or methods within pandas.  (There is for example a current discussion about how numpy gets a different answer than the analogous function in pandas due to precision issues.)

Comment: Thank you, your example clarified everything for me!